# @Parameter1 is not a parameter for procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, c#-4.0, stored-procedures

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[NST_InsertTblGenLedDet]
        @GHDHeader int,
      @Gldtype text,
      @GldAccount text,
      @GldDate DateTime, 
      @GldVoucherType int,
      @GldDebit   float=null,
      @GldCredit float= null,
      @GldDtaLine int= null
AS
DECLARE @ERR INT
BEGIN TRANSACTION
Insert into [TblGenLedDet] 
(GHDHeader,Gldtype,GldAccount,GldDate, GldVoucherType, GldDebit,GldCredit,GldDtaLine)
 values (@GHDHeader,@Gldtype,@GldAccount,@GldDate, @GldVoucherType, @GldDebit,@GldCredit,@GldDtaLine)



SET @ERR = @@Error
IF @ERR = 0   
BEGIN
      COMMIT TRANSACTION

END
ELSE
BEGIN
      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
      RETURN @ERR               
END
```

[image]

I am getting this error again and again though i have specified the parameter name as @GldCredit it shows Parameter name as Parameter1

Comment: Are you possibly re-using `sqlCommand` without creating a new object or clearing out the parameter collection?

Comment: SqlCommand sqlCommand = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();
          sqlCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
          sqlCommand.CommandText = "[dbo].[NST_InsertTblGenLedHead]";

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your code, you initialize `gldCredit`, but then update `gldDebit`.  Your `gldCredit` parameter never has any of its members set, and thus, has its `ParaameterName` defautled to `"@Paremeter1"`.

It looks like you copy/pasted the `gldDebit` code for setting up your parameter, but forgot to update all the references in the new block of code to point to `gldCredit`.

Answer (score 1):

Sharing for future readers -

This error is also thrown when the `@ParameterName` in your `C#` code is different than `@Parameter_Name` in `stored-procedures`.

Comment: How embarrassing simple - an errant underscore kicked my rear. I won't even tell you how much time I've spent troubleshooting this very issue today.